# You attempted to import /src/assets/images which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported

Tags: reactjs, image, import, assets

> ***Problem***:  My **assets** file is inside of **src** folder. But terminal showing error that my **assets** file is outside of **src/**. Which causes me unable to import images inside of my file **\src\home\home.js**

[image: here is the picture of issue I'm facing]

Comment: Please provide a full image which contains the path of each code file

Comment: Path of the file at line 2 on the right should start from where the file starts. For example, if you're at the home.js like it is indicated on the left panel, the path should be "../assets/images/banner.jpg"

Comment: @hungdoansy, new problem: how will I import the image, If my image location is this -> **\src\assets\images\banner.jpg** and my file location of where I want to use is this **\src\Pages\home\home.js**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the relative path and try if that works!
in your case: `import Banner from "../assets/images/banner.jpg"`

Comment: _**new problem:**_ how will I import the image, If my image location is this **\src\assets\images\banner.jpg** and my file location of where I want to use is this **\src\Pages\home\home.js**

Comment: please tell me in this way! _**"../assets/images/banner.jpg"**_

Comment: sure man! let me explain how relative paths work!
**"./filename"**  will look for the file in the current directory.
every **../"** is one directory above the current file.
So to reach your desired directory, you will travel two directories up, from _home^pages^src_, and then select the path from there, so **"/assets/images/banner.jpg."** . So because you want to go from your file two directories up first, your path becomes: **"../../assets/images/banner.jpg"**